# Thymeleaf is trying to build a html which does not exist and which is not called anywhere

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to build a spring mvc app with spring boot and thymeleaf. I am trying to create a form to insert an object into my data base (something which I already do in my app and is working) but I constantly find this error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/error.html]")
(...)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/error.html]
(...)
```

This is the problem you usually find when you are trying to reference a template which does not exist or has a different name. **Here's the thing**. There is no Error.html in my views' folder as you can see in the print below:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

**EDIT with more information:**

Below you can find the endpoints which are giving me trouble:

```
@GetMapping("{id}/add-expense")
public String expensesForm(Model model, @PathVariable Long id){
   model.addAttribute("expense", new Expenses());
   model.addAttribute("budgetId", id);
   return "expenseForm";
}

@PostMapping("{id}/add-expense")
public String expenseSubmitted(@ModelAttribute Expenses expense, @PathVariable Long id, Model model){
   Budgets budget = budgetsRepository.getById(id);
   if(budget != null){
      budget.addExpense(expense);
      expense.setBudget(budget);
      expensesRepository.saveAndFlush(expense);
   }
   else{
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "not all variables there");
   }
   model.addAttribute("expense", expense);
   return "expenseResult";
}
```

The GET endpoint seems to be working as intended. When I load the "id/add-expense" path it displays the page "expenseForm" correctly. The problem comes when I try to submit the form in the "expenseForm" template and go to the POST for "id/add-expenses". That is when I get a 400 bad request response. I am lead to believe that the problem might be that the "expenseForm" cannot correctly populate the @ModelAttribute in the POST method but I can't say why or how to fix it. In the console, I am given the error above which tells me that Thymeleaf cannot find the template for "error.html".

expenseForm.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Expense Creation</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div th:insert="fragments/navbar.html"> </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Expense Creation</h3>
      </div>
      <form action="#" th:action="@{/budgets/{id}/add-expense(id = ${budgetId})}" th:object="${expense}" method="post">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{expenses_name}" /></p>
        <p>Amount: <input type="number" th:field="*{expenses_amount}" /></p>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" th:field="*{expenses_date}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

expenseResult.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Expense Creation</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div th:insert="fragments/navbar.html"> </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Expense Created</h3>
            </div>
            <p th:text="'Name: ' + ${expense.expenses_name}" />
            <p th:text="'Amount: ' + ${expense.expenses_amount}" />
            <p th:text="'Date: ' + ${expense.expenses_date}" />
            <a href="expenses">Submit another expense</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/budgetScript.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Class Expenses:

```
@Entity(name = "expenses")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Expenses {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long expenses_id;
    private String expenses_name;
    private Integer expenses_amount;
    private Date expenses_date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
            name = "budget_expenses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "expenses_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "budgets_id"))
    private Budgets budget;

    //Gettes setters and constructor
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 2 after changing the name of "expenseResult.html" to "error.html":**

So I decided to follow the tip from [andrewJames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12567365/andrewjames) and I changed the name of "expenseResult.html" to "error.html". I also changed the return value in the POST method from 'return "expenseResult"' to 'return "error"' and I am no longer given the 400 bad request error on the application. Instead, I am given the "error.html" page but the fields for expense.expenses_name, expense.expenses_amount or expense.expenses_date are not shown in the page. It is just an empty page with the "Expense Creation" text. In the console I receive a new error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "expense.expenses_name" (template: "error" - line 19, col 16)
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'expenses_name' cannot be found on null
(...)
```

From what we can see, the application cannot retrieve the fields from null, meaning that the @ModelAttribute Expenses expense is not returning the correct values from the form page. It more or less confirms my suspicion that the problem was in the modelAttribute but I continue to not know how to correct the problem since I have tried to verify multiple times if everything was okay and I found no issue. I also don't understand why it is looking for a "error.html" file considering that I had no prior mention to such a file in my code and project.

**EDIT 3 after using ModelandView intead of ModelAttribute:**

Following [dsp_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119161/dsp-user)'s suggestion. I started by hardcoding the path with "/budgets/10/add-expense" instead of using {id} and the problem remained, which makes me believe that the problem is not the path.

I started using the ModelAndView, as can be shown below, but I continued to have the same problem as before (400 bad request).

```
@PostMapping("{id}/add-expense")
    public ModelAndView expenseSubmitted(@ModelAttribute("expenses") Expenses expenses, @PathVariable Long id, Model model){
        System.out.println("here");
        Budgets budget = budgetsRepository.getById(id);
        if(budget != null){
            budget.addExpense(expenses);
            expenses.setBudget(budget);
            expensesRepository.saveAndFlush(expenses);
        }
        else{
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "not all variables there");
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("expenseResult");
        modelAndView.addObject("expense", expenses);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**EDIT 4 to add the Budgets logic:**

Budgets:

```
@Entity(name = "budgets")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Budgets {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long budgets_id;
    private String budgets_name;
    private String budgets_description;
    private Integer budgets_amount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "budget")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Expenses> expenses;

    @Transient
    public float budgets_expense_sum = 0;

//Gettes setters and constructor
}
```

Budget Creation Endpoints:

```
@GetMapping("new")
    public String budgetsForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("budget", new Budgets());
        return "budgetForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("new")
    public String budgetSubmitted(@ModelAttribute Budgets budget, Model model){
        budgetsRepository.saveAndFlush(budget);
        model.addAttribute("budget", budget);
        return "budgetResult";
```

BudgetForm.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Budget Creation</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div th:insert="fragments/navbar.html"> </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Budget Creation</h3>
      </div>
      <form action="#" th:action="@{/budgets/new}" th:object="${budget}" method="post">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{budgets_name}" /></p>
        <p>Description: <input type="text" th:field="*{budgets_description}" /></p>
        <p>Monthly Amount: <input type="number" th:field="*{budgets_amount}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

BudgetResult.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Budget Creation</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div th:insert="fragments/navbar.html"> </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Budget Created</h3>
            </div>
            <p th:text="'Name: ' + ${budget.budgets_name}" />
            <p th:text="'Description: ' + ${budget.budgets_description}" />
            <p th:text="'Amount: ' + ${budget.budgets_amount}" />
            <a href="new">Submit another message</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/budgetScript.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us a little more of what you're trying to do and perhaps then we'll be able to help.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I have provided an edit with more information regarding my issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if you create the missing `error.html` file? Maybe you will get a different, more relevant error in that case. Worth a try?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have done what you suggested and I have documented my findings in a second Edit. Hope it helps and thank you.

Comment: @AshenWaltz,  Can you put System.out.println(expense.toString()) somewhere at the beginning of expenseSubmitted and then submit your form? If you don't see it in the console, then your page doesn't get hit at all.

Comment: Also, by convention, Spring boot will try to redirect to error.html whenever an error occurs ( but since you don't have it/didn't have it, Thymeleaf complained about it)

Comment: Ok I see that explains the error.html. I have placed a println in the first line of the expenseSubmitted and it does not print. so yes I believe it is crashing even before entering the endpoint. I have also verified the url path the post is trying to reach and it seems to be the correct one. I remember that, when I removed the ModelAttribute argument it managed to enter the method which lead me to believe that the problem was with the ModelAttribute.

Comment: @AshenWaltz, can you replace Model.addAttribute with ModelAndView.addObject in your post method and see if that makes any difference? When using ModelAndView dont forget to also ModelAndView.setView("expenseResult") and have your endpoint return a ModelAndView rather than a String. But first just try to hardcode the url in expenseForm.html (e.g th:action=""@{/budgets/some-id-here/add-expense?id=10" to see if the url is the problem.

Comment: @dsp_user I have implemented your suggestions and have documented my findings in another edit (#3). The problem remained unfortunately.

Comment: @AshenWaltz, ok, I think the problem is most likely that you're not sending a well-formed Expense entity to your endpoint. Post the Budgets class as well  and I'll try to recreate your example when I find the time.

Comment: @dsp_user thank you for your help! I have provided a 4th edit with the logic for Budgets. If you need anything else let me know. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AshenWaltz, since you don't really (need to) have a many to many relationship between the expenses and budgets tables, I would suggest that you simply add an extra column to expenses table ( budget_id ) and adjust the expenses entity accordingly and then replace `@JoinTable` with `@JoinColumn(name="budget_id")`.  You will also need to add that extra field to your expenses form but I think this change alone might be enough to get your app working. Let's keep things simple